# Ich meine, so richtig was bauen, was man dann nachher benutzen kann

Tags: sentence-structure

Is the sentence after 'meinen" a Nebensatz?...

Why does he say here "so richtig was bauen"...., why not:

> "Ich meine, so richtig bauen was man dann nachher benutzen kann"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentence

> „Ich meine, so richtig was bauen, was man dann nachher benutzen kann“

is very colloquial and typical for spoken German. In written form, you would more likely say something like

> „[...] **Damit meine ich**, so richtig **etwas zu** bauen, **das** man dann nachher benutzen kann“
>
> or
>
> „[...] **Ich meine damit**, so richtig **etwas zu** bauen, **was** man dann nachher benutzen kann“.

Thus, in the original sentence, the first **was** is short for **etwas**, and the second **was** is a relative pronoun. It is also clear now that the sentence cannot stand alone; it rather explicates something, referred to by the word **damit**, which has been said before.

To answer the introductory question: Indeed, the part „so richtig etwas zu bauen“ is a Nebensatz, which is constructed with an *infinitive with zu*, but where **zu** was simply left out.

Comment: Die Antwort spricht mir aus dem Herzen. Man könnte aber noch hinzufügen, dass ein Satz wie dieser niemals für sich alleine steht sondern nur in einem Kontext Sinn hat: einem Kontext nämlich, auf den sich das "Ich meine" bezieht, also eine Aussage ähnlicher Intention, von der der Sprecher dann aber meint, sie sei möglicherweise nicht präzise genug verstanden worden.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, ich hab's mit eingebaut. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is colloquial spoken German.

The sentence doesn't work by itself, but relies on an implied subject and verb from a previous sentence, probably a question.

e.g.

> [Will er das wirklich?][Kann er das?]. Ich meine, so richtig etwas...
>   *implies*
>   will er so richtig etwas...
>   kann er so richtig etwas...

The rest of the sentence is full of colloquialisms:

- *Ich meine" means "I mean" and it's used in the same sense as it would in English
- "So richtig" means "really", "so" just emphasizes "richtig"
- "Was" is short for "etwas"
- "Was" is used instead of "das" to start the subordinate clause